# Can Vieta's formulas be generalized?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-theorem

I think binomial theorem is just a special case of expansion by Vieta's formulas. For example, Vieta's formula can be used to expand:
$$(x-a_n)^{k_n}(x-a_{n-1})^{k_{n-1}}.....(x-a_2)^{k_2}(x-a_1)^{k_1}$$
Binomial expansion is just a special case of this when all the roots $a_1,a_2,.......,a_n$ are identical.
Now, the polynomial expansion of
$$(x-a_n)^{k_n}(x-a_{n-1})^{k_{n-1}}.....(x-a_2)^{k_2}(x-a_1)^{k_1}$$
has $k_1+k_2+...+k_{n-1}+k_n$ roots. If all $k_1,k_2,.....,k_n$ are integers then according to Vieta's formulae the coefficient of $x^{k_1+k_2+...+k_{n-1}+k_n-c}$ in the expansion will be $(-1)^c$ multiplied by the sums of products of the roots taken $c$ at a time.

Now, if $k_1,k_2,........k_n$ are non-integers, then there'll be an infinite expansion. Can Vieta's formulas be expanded to non-integer $k_1,k_2,........k_n$? Just like Binomial theorem is generalized to non-integer exponents?

Comment: How are you imagining a generalization? Vieta's formula is a statement about the coefficients of polynomials. If the $k_i$ are not integers, then the function is no longer a polynomial.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I think that's what generalization means. Generalize it for non-polynomials.

Comment: Right, but my point is what would the analog of the coefficients be for nonpolynomials?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise There's no analog of coefficients. For example, $\sqrt{x-1}(x-4)^{\frac{1}{3}}(x-2)$ has an infinite expansion. Forget Vieta's formulas. Can you give a general rule for the coefficient of $x^k$ in such expansions?